# display a message to a label in vb.net at specified times during the day

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display a sentence in a text box at a 5 specific times during the day automatically. for example:
at 5:30 AM,
Textbox1.text = "breakfast"
at 7:30 AM
textbox1.text = "leave for school",
etc.
a timer can just start when the application is launched, although it needs to refer to the local time or some constant time as the program needs to output at the same time each day of the week without me having to change it manually.

Comment: Of course it can just be a `Timer` that starts when the application is launched. The `Interval` controls when the `Timer` raises a `Tick` event.  Simply set that to the appropriate value.  If the application starts at 2.37 PM and you need a message to appear a 5.00 PM then set the `Interval` to the number of milliseconds in 2 hours and 23 minutes.  It's simple maths.

Comment: the program needs to be automatic and hence every time i open the program, changing the time wouldn't be automatic. thankyou anyway

Comment: You're confusing "automatic" and "magic".  Automatic means that your code does it without user intervention.  If you write the code to do what you want then what you want will happen automatically.  See my answer below for a demonstration of exactly what i said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do it is something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set the interval at startup.
    Timer1.Interval = CInt(GetNextNotificationTime().Subtract(Date.Now).TotalMilliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Set the interval at each notification.
    Timer1.Interval = CInt(GetNextNotificationTime().Subtract(Date.Now).TotalMilliseconds)

    'Not sure whether this is required when the Interval changes or not.
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()

    'Do the work here.
End Sub

Private Function GetNextNotificationTime() As Date
    '...
End Function
```

How you implement that `GetNextNotificationTime` method depends on how the notification times are stored.  The `Timer` will then `Tick` only when a notification is due.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Kudos for writing elegant code. I also think it is complete overkill :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this with a `Timer` and you wouldn't have to do any math...

Every time the `Timer` raises a `Tick` event, you check the value of: `System.DateTime.Today.Now.ToString("HH:mm")`. If it is equal to your preset time, change the text in the `TextBox`

Comment: You need to write above mentioned code in multi-threading, so your program can provide other functionalities and mean while in background program checks for system time with predefined time to display message if needed.

Comment: No you don't. An enabled timer runs on it's own thread already. The logic for checking the time and updating the label would either be written into the Timer.Tick event handler, or better written in a sub that is called from the Ti'mer.Tick handler.

Comment: Yeah what @DavidWilson said :-)